# Object files with visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker

I have a main file `main.cpp` which include `myclass.h`. I also have `myclass.o` and `myclass.cpp`. The visual studio project is only using the files `main.cpp` and `myclass.h.`

This compile:

```
#include "myclass.h"
int main()
{

   return 0;
}
```

This does not:

```
#include "myclass.h"
int main()
{
   myclass M{};

   return 0;
}
```

which gives a link error - probably because the `myclass.cpp` or `myclass.o` is not included in the project.

I would prefer to include only `myclass.o` since compiling this class is very problematic.
See 
https://forum.qt.io/topic/8492/solved-cannot-get-quazip-test-to-work/3 
if you are curious of which library I am using.

To my question:
Can I compile and use the class with only the header and the object file, i.e without the .cpp file at all?

Thanks!

Comment: Add `myclass.cpp` to project

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio generates a .obj file as its intermediate format.  gcc and gcc are the ones that produce a .o file.  You can include this in your project or, since libraries rarely have a single compile unit, you can build a .lib file and include that.  Be warned, though, that the compiled units must be compiled using the exact same compiler switches such as run time library and etc. as you are using in you project.  It is often simpler to simply compile the file from source.

We can also talk about using a DLL but that seems to be beyond the scope of your question and also introduces the complication of calling conventions.

Comment: It is the same compiler. 101% on that. If i include the .o file, do i need the .cpp file? Is it problematic if it(.cpp) is in the same dictionary if they are not needed. How do i build a .lib?

Comment: Just add the CPP file to project.

Comment: It doesn't matter if they are built with the same compiler.  What does matter is the calling conventions and possible conflicts between the standard libraries that they compile against.  For instance, your .obj may be linked against the dynamic run-time and your application set up for the static.  We you linked the project, you would get very strange linker errors.

Comment: The easiest way in visual studio to build a library is to select that option when you start a new project.  Again, you have to be careful to match compiler settings within the library project and the project that will include it.